# ggplot2 geom_bar only fills with the last color in gWidgets ggraphics

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo, gwidgets

I tried to draw a bar plot using `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar()` onto a `gWdigets`'s `ggraphics()` canvas but the bars all share same color (which is the last color in the palette).  On the other hand, if the same is drawn onto base R's `windows()`, then each bar has its own color (the desired behavior).  I'm not sure if this rendering issue is due to `gWidgetsRGtk2`, `ggplot2`, or `cairoDevice`.  Any idea?

Here is an example code to reproduce the issue:

```
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(ggplot2)
x <- data.frame(sex=factor(c("M", "F")), value=c(1,2))
fig <- ggplot(data=x, aes(sex, value, fill=sex)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

ggraphics(container=gwindow())
print(fig) # Both bars use the last color incorrectly.

windows()
fig # Each bar uses its own color correctly.
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1        gWidgetsRGtk2_0.0-83 cairoDevice_2.22    
[4] gWidgets_0.0-54      RGtk2_2.20.31       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-43      grid_3.2.1      
 [5] plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5    
 [9] stringi_0.5-5    reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     proto_0.3-10    
[13] tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: I can't really test right now, but my guess is that the issue lies in the `cairoDevice` package, though it may be in how `gWidgets2` calls those features.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add color option for ggplot at 
fig <- ggplot(data=x, aes(sex, value, color=sex, fill=sex)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

seems it works.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion with `color=sex` but it still doesn't work.